# Marvel API and Insomnia (or Postman): how do I pass the hash value that's required?

Tags: javascript, request, postman, insomnia

I'm a relatively new Javascript programmer and I'm experimenting with the Marvel API (I need to access the images for a project) and having a little trouble wrapping my head around the requirements.

As I understand it, you need to pass a `hash` and a `ts` (timestamp, I presume), when calling the API from a server-side app.  But I don't see in the documentation that this is required when using a client-side app.

I tried to do some basic endpoint testing with Insomnia and I receive the message `"You must provide a hash."`.  Apparently I need the `hash` for client-side access as well?

I have seen some NodeJS examples that show you how to generate the `hash` (for example, https://www.raymondcamden.com/2014/02/02/Examples-of-the-Marvel-API), but nothing for the client side (that I could find).  I also don't know how I would generate this within Insomnia (or Postman).  Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

I'd also like to ask what role the `authorized domains` play when accessing the Marvel API from a local machine.  Do I need to add `localhost` to this list?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: have you acquired your api key at least?

Comment: Yes -- public and private, although I'm not sure where the private key comes into play.  I see from examples on the web that one can access the API client-side using only the public key -- so I'm trying to set that up.  But I don't know why it won't work with API testing apps like Postman/Insomnia -- don't they simulate client-side calls?  I found the following article that references calling Marvel with Postman, but he has to generate `hash` and `ts` values to pass to Postman -- and I'm not clear why he needed to, if Postman emulates a client, or how he generated those...

Comment: https://medium.com/@DKUSHandOJ/apis-and-postman-deliver-184ce17bf631

Comment: so obviously you can talk to the api in two ways i.e. by registering a domain it recognises or by signing a request with md5(timestamp + pubkey + privKey)

Comment: OK, thanks.  Would 'localhost' then be the domain I need to register to test locally -- i.e. from my machine -- using either Postman or Insomnia?  How can I generate the hash within those two programs?

Comment: Postman does not expose an api to generate hash for you (i think). You can only do that on the server side with built-in crypto type libs. So maybe find a service that you can call via postman scripting to pass the parameters (ts + pub + priv) and get back the hash which you can use, but I would advise against this as you expose your private key to the service which is supposed to be secret.

Comment: Thanks, I think I see the way forward.  If I use the apikey from a _client-side_ application, I neither need to register a domain nor provide a hash.   But if I use a _server-side_ app (e.g. Express), I need to register 'localhost' and provide a hash and timestamp.  Is that correct?

Comment: Not sure you can use localhost directly. maybe try https://ngrok.com/ to help you tunnel your localhost and get a url with which you register with them.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Follow the steps:

1. Pick an API Endpoint. eg: https://gateway.marvel.com:443/v1/public/characters
2. Use a query value for ts. ts could be timestamp or any long string.
   eg: ts=thesoer
3. Generate a MD5 hash of `ts+privatekey+publickey` through code or preferrably online. `eg: md5(ts + privKey + pubKey)`
   For md5 hash: http://www.md5.cz/
4. Join the dots. `URL?ts=val&apikey=key&hash=md5Hash`.
   eg. https://gateway.marvel.com:443/v1/public/characters?ts=thesoer&apikey=001ac6c73378bbfff488a36141458af2&hash=72e5ed53d1398abb831c3ceec263f18b

Comment: I follow these steps and have a 401 error more details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67789504/the-passed-api-key-is-invalid-with-marvel-api-in-postman

Answer (score 7):

Add a pre-requisite script to your postman collection.

```
var pubkey = "your_public_key";
var pvtkey = "your_private_key";
var ts = new Date().getTime();

pm.environment.set("ts", ts)
pm.environment.set("apikey", pubkey)

var message = ts+pvtkey+pubkey;
var a = CryptoJS.MD5(message);
pm.environment.set("hash", a.toString())
```

And then you can make your calls like such

```
https://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters?ts={{ts}}&apikey={{apikey}}&hash={{hash}}
```

See [this](https://github.com/doamaral/postmanmarvelapi) collection.

Regarding your authorized domains, add your public IP.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I think **pm.environment.set** is outdated. I changed for **postman.setEnvironmentVariable** and it works

Comment: You are geinous! Thanks a lot. @dougfabris Tested with pm, still works (with the latest version of postman).