# The passed API key is invalid with Marvel API in Postman

Tags: api, hash, localhost, authorization, ip-address

I'm trying to make a request to [Marvel API](https://developer.marvel.com/) on Postman but I got Error code: 401

```
{
    "code": "InvalidCredentials",
    "message": "The passed API key is invalid."
}
```

I used [this website](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/) to get a timestamp and use [this](https://passwordsgenerator.net/md5-hash-generator/) to get MD5 hash

I send in the request these parameters
apikey,ts,hash as mentioned [here](https://developer.marvel.com/documentation/authorization) but still got the error

I tried to add my IP to authorized referrers as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57874907/4979652) but it wouldn't help too

Answer (score 2):

I was having this problem as well.
The following helped me:

Straight from the My Developer Account, after adding your IP address in the additional referral, I clicked interactive document.

Not sure if you still need the answer, but that's how I got mine to work.